# Copy device from one registry to another Google IoT Core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-iot

I have one device, 'XYZ' in test registry as i have to follow an entire process to check few things. Then after it is successful, i want to register this device to proper registry, say camera registry and following with unregister from test registry. 
So, is copying a device-object from one registry to another possible? If not, what is the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The registry of a device cannot be updated, and there's no feature to copy one device from one registry to another. So, the best approach on this depends on your use case.

I created a small Python script that can migrate the devices, I tested it in some of mine and it seems to work correctly for all their properties.

```py
from google.cloud import iot_v1

def move_device(project_id, cloud_region, registry_source, registry_target, device_id):

    # Instantiate client
    client = iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient()

    # Source device path to get its information, and deleting it
    source_device_path = client.device_path(project_id, cloud_region, registry_source, device_id)

    # Get device
    device = client.get_device(source_device_path)

    # Clean values for new device
    device.name = ''
    device.config.cloud_update_time.seconds= 0
    device.config.cloud_update_time.nanos= 0
    device.config.version = 0 
    device.num_id = 0

    # Create the device in the new registry
    client.create_device(client.registry_path(project_id, cloud_region, registry_target), device)

    # Uncomment to delete the original device registry
    # client.delete_device(source_device_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    project_id='my-project'
    cloud_region='my-region'
    registry_source='my-registry-source'
    registry_target='my-registry-target'
    device_id='my-device'

    move_device(project_id, cloud_region, registry_source, registry_target, device_id)
```

This script is using the [google-cloud-iot library](https://googleapis.dev/python/iot/latest/gapic/v1/api.html), which you can install with pip.

```
pip install google-cloud-iot
```

I took the idea from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices#top_of_page), I hope it works for you.

Comment: This is exactly how i did that. Thought there is some inbuilt functionality but nonetheless thanks as it will work.